# Laravel, passing new function to blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a working class file, controller and view that show different samples of data, but I'm currently adding a new function which grabs data from the database, passing that to the controller and defining it, then passing it to the blade/view.

I'm not really doing anything differently than the other functions but the data is not showing in my blade. The placeholder is spaced appropriately on the webpage but the data doesn't show up. The query is getting results and the function is passing to the blade because the foreach is creating additional rows. I'm thinking I'm using improper syntax for the variables in my blade which is why my data isn't actually showing.

Any help appreciated here:

**EMPLOYEE.php**

```
class employeeCalls
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->yyyy = date('Y');
        $this->pyyy = $this->yyyy - 1;
        $this->from = "{$this->pyyy}-01-01";
        $this->through = $this->pyyy . '-' . date('m-d');
        $this->fullYear = "{$this->pyyy}-12-31";
        $this->newFrom = "{$this->yyyy}-01-01";
        $this->newThrough = date('Y-m-d'); 
    }

public function sample($employee)
    {
        $employee = (int) $employee;
        $from = $this->from;
        $through = $this->through;
        $newFrom = $this->newFrom;
        $newThrough = $this->newThrough;
        $FullYear = $this->fullYear;

        $sql = "
                select employee, 'PRIOR' as Range, count(*) as count
                from empCalls
                where employee = {$employee}
                AND fordate between '{$from}' and '{$through}'
                group by employee
            union all
                select employee, 'CURRENT' as Range, count(*) as count
                from empCalls
                where employee = {$employee}
                AND fordate between '{$newFrom}' and '{$newThrough}'
                group by employee
            union ALL
                select employee, 'FULL' as Range, count(*) as count
                from empCalls
                where employee = {$employee}
                AND fordate between '{$from}' and '{$FullYear}'
                group by employee
        ";

        return Connection::runQuery($sql);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeController.php**

```
    $employeeCalls = new employeeCalls();

    $samples = $employeeCalls->sample($this->slsno);

    return view('Employee.index')
            ->with('slsno', $this->slsno)
            ->with('samples', $samples);
    }
```

**blade.php**

```
<div class="md-card-content">
    @foreach($samples as $sample)
            <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $sample['PRIOR'] }}</span></div>
            <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-medium">2017 YTD</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr />
            <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $sample['CURRENT'] }}</span></div>
            <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-medium">2018 YTD</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr />
            <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $sample['FULL'] }}</span></div>
            <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-medium">2017 Full Year</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr />
    @endforeach
</div>
```

UPDATE:

This is what dumps from $samples

```
array:3 [▼
0 => array:3 [▼
"employee" => "495"
"RANGE" => "PRIOR"
"COUNT" => "119"
]
1 => array:3 [▼
"employee" => "495"
"RANGE" => "CURRENT"
"COUNT" => "68"
]
2 => array:3 [▼
"employee" => "495"
"RANGE" => "FULL"
"COUNT" => "440"
]
]
```

Comment: dump out whatever is in $samples, is there anything?

Comment: Hard to say. It's unclear what `Connection::runQuery` does, or returns. Why have you bypassed all of Laravel's model and database functionality for your own database calls like this?

Comment: @Andrew I did a dd on the blade with expected values , posted above in my update

Comment: so it has data?? have you inspected the page? maybe md-card-content is hidden??

Comment: is your blade template named correctly? .blade.php

Comment: Nope, it's not hidden and all the html shows appropriately. Even the foreach generates additional cards for the data

Comment: It is. The whole blade other than this data, shows fine

Comment: could try @foreach($samples as $key => $sample)

Comment: could dump out the $sample within the foreach

Comment: what you want to display? the count?

Comment: @afsalc yes, so if you look at the array above, the count should be displayed for the corresponding row. So Count for PRIOR should be in that row, count for CURRENT in that row and so on

Comment: @Andrew when I DD the sample within the loop I get:
array:3 [▼
  "SLSNO" => "495"
  "RANGE" => "PRIOR"
  "COUNT" => "119"
]

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your blade.php

```
<div class="md-card-content">
            <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $samples[0]['COUNT'] }}</span></div>
            <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-medium">2017 YTD</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr />
            <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $samples[1]['COUNT'] }}</span></div>
            <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-medium">2018 YTD</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr />
            <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $samples[2]['COUNT'] }}</span></div>
            <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-medium">2017 Full Year</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr />

</div>
```

Comment: Wow, perfect! And much more simple than I thought..Thanks so much

Comment: Question: If I wanted to get a percentage change between prior and current, would you reccommend doing that in the blade at the div or in the controller?

Comment: if only for display purpose i prefer view than controller

Comment: It is only for display, but it's just simple math so I didn't know if that would be ok in the view. It's basically just (current-prior)/prior

Answer (score 0):

On your EmployeeController.php

declare an private variable  protected $data = array(); like below

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    protected $data = array();
```

and on the function modify

```
$employeeCalls = new employeeCalls();
$samples = $employeeCalls->sample($this->slsno);
return view('Employee.index')
       ->with('slsno', $this->slsno)
       ->with('samples', $samples);
}
```

like below

```
$employeeCalls = new employeeCalls();
$this->data['samples'] = $employeeCalls->sample($this->slsno);
$this->data['slsno'] = $this->slsno;
return view('Employee.index')
        ->with($this->data);
}
```

this will fix the issue i hope

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be in chaining with() method.
Try change this:

```
return view('Employee.index')
        ->with('slsno', $this->slsno)
        ->with('samples', $samples);
```

for that:

```
return view('Employee.index', [
  'slsno' => $this->slsno, 
  'samples' => $samples
]);
```

Comment: But anything else in there doesn't have an issue showing up