# Printing data from controller to blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to print some data coming from my controller into a blade, everything else from the controller, in the same structure, is printing fine.

I think I have syntax wrong in the blade. I have a variable for $dataSample returning query results.

When I dump dataSample I get this:

```
array:1 [▼
0 => {#798 ▼
+"current": "2840"
+"prior": "2257"
+"full": "2700"
}
]
```

I'm trying to put those three values in the blade like so:

```
<div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample ['prior'] }}</span></div>
<div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample ['current'] }}</span></div>
<div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample ['full'] }}</span></div>
```

I've tried with and without single and double quotes, upper and lowercase but it just won't print my data out. All the html loads and there are no errors, I think I'm just declaring them  incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, passing new function to blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800093/laravel-passing-new-function-to-blade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is array into array, you need this

```
 <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample[0]['prior'] }}</span></div>
 <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample[0]['current'] }}</span></div>
 <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample[0]['full'] }}</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are declaring them incorrectly

You need to loop through them and print

```
@foreach($datasample as $sample)
  @foreach($sample as $item => $value)
   <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $value}}</span></div>
  @endforeach
@endofreach
```

Always better to do this, instead of getting the specific index.

Additionally, if you are unsure if the nested array will be an array, check with `@if` inside the foreach

Answer (score 0):

Use `->first()` to get single result instead `->get()` in your query.

And in your blade get values as `$dataSample->prior`

```
  <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample->prior ?? '' }}</span></div>
 <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample->current ?? '' }}</span></div>
 <div class="uk-float-right uk-margin-small-right"><span class="uk-text-medium uk-text-center">{{ $dataSample->full ?? '' }}</span></div>
```

In your current result you can use like this

```
 $dataSample[0]->prior
```